# Use grep/awk to extract server names from a file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file which has multiple line of the following pattern -

Serverfile -

```
permit from www.hadooptest.abc.net to www.ha1.abc.net:80/TCP, 443/TCP

permit from www.hadooptest.abc.net to www.apz2.abc.net:443/TCP

permit from www.hadooptest.abc.net to www.aln.abc.net, www.klm.abc.net:80/TCP, 443/TCP
```

I would like to come up with a script which extracts all the server names in the file.  I have played around with multiple iterations of grep and awk but so far have not been able to figure out a way to ONLY extract the server name. For example, “grep -o 'to .*abc.net’ Serverfile” give me the following output -

```
$ grep -o ' to.*abc.net' Serverfile 
 to www.ha1.abc.net
 to www.apz2.abc.net
 to www.aln.abc.net, www.klm.abc.net
```

I can’t use this in a script as the individual server names are not being extracted and also there are some lines with multiple server names like the last one with www.aln.abc.net and www.klm.abc.net.

Thanks!!

Comment: what is the issue, to avoid left `"to"` substring from the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grep solution is good but returns both results:

```
$ grep -o '[A-Za-z0-9_\.-]*.abc.net'  <<<"permit from www.hadooptest.abc.net to www.ha1.abc.net:80/TCP, 443/TCP"
www.hadooptest.abc.net   #You don't want this one
www.ha1.abc.net
```

I would use something like:

```
$ grep -Po 'to \K[A-Za-z0-9_\.-]*.abc.net'  <<<"permit from www.hadooptest.abc.net to www.ha1.abc.net:80/TCP, 443/TCP"
www.ha1.abc.net
```

Or just `$ grep -Po 'to \Kwww[.].*.abc.net'`

This uses the `grep -Po` => PCRE - perl regexps, with `\K` operator (=forget previous)

Or even you can use another tool:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*to )([A-Za-z0-9_\.-]*.abc.net)(.*)/\2/g'  <<<"permit from www.hadooptest.abc.net to www.ha1.abc.net:80/TCP, 443/TCP"
www.ha1.abc.net
```

Or just `$ sed -r 's/(.*to )(www[.].*.abc.net)(.*)/\2/g'`

Just replace the part `<<<"..."` at the end with `yourfile`.

Comment: Thanks! this is much more elgant !!

Comment: @user168115 Welcome. If you are happy with those solutions , you can accept it as answer by clicking the green tick.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... i might have found the answer :) -

```
grep -o '[A-Za-z0-9_\.-]*.abc.net' Serverfile | more 
www.hadooptest.abc.net
www.ha1.abc.net
www.hadooptest.abc.net
www.apz2.abc.net
www.hadooptest.abc.net
www.aln.abc.net
www.klm.abc.net
```